# How to add class based on location and corresponding href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I have a menu with a simple markup , and my aim is to add a class to the menu `<li>` item automatically by the name of the current page ....

The relevant Markup is :

```
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li >    
            <a href="page_example_one.html">

            <i class="icon-time"></i>

            Timeline</a>    
        </li>    
        <li >    
            <a href="page_example_two.html">

            <i class="icon-cogs"></i>

            Page Two</a>    
        </li>
.... Many other elements 
    </ul>
```

What I need to get is very simple , when I am on a certain page ( assume page_example_one.html
) I would need the corresponding `<li>` element to have an additional class like so

```
<li class="active">

    <a href="page_example_one.html">

    <i class="icon-time"></i>

    Timeline</a>

</li>
```

I tried to do that with jQuerylike so :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

     // Get the current page name ( pathname)
            var currentUrl =  jQuery(location).attr('pathname');

            // Get the element ( try at least )
            var currentMenuItem = jQuery("sub-menu li a[href='" + currentUrl + "']");

            // Add the class
            currentMenuItem.addClass("active");

                //Tried also something like this : 
                // jQuery("sub-menu li a[href='" + currentUrl + "']").find('a').addClass("active");


        });
```

both the methods above failed for me - ( the commented one with VAR , and the concatenated )
But because my JS skills are very low, I can not really see what I am doing wrong ( probably somehting really obvious to someone who knows JS )

After resolving this issue, I would also like to know how to add spans or classes also to a parent menu item ( in case of sub menu ) based on the current page link ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentMenuItem = jQuery("a[href='" + currentUrl + "']").parent()
```

Add a demo [here](http://jsbin.com/kizuhi/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: What is the reason to remove the other tags `sub-menu` and `li`?I assume you did it to allow the simple use of `parent()` - but  is that correct to do in all situations ? I might have other `<a>` elements on the page with the same URL ...

Comment: Using less tag selectors can make the query faster in your case. If your page has other elements with the same URL, you can use more `tag` selectors or `class` selectors to query. Please show us your html and we can get more information. I guess the `sub-menu` string is a `className`? If it is a `className`, you must use `.sub-menu`

Comment: This is a jsbin demo. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/kizuhi/2/edit?html,css,js,output) here. I think it works.

Comment: If you have elements with the same URL and can not resolve it yourself, you can email me and I will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

target the submenu by its class `ul.sub-menu`. alternativley you can also target more generally all items with the class by `.sub-menu`. `sub-menu` alone would target a theoretical `<sub-menu>` element.

than get the parent (the `<li>`) of the link:

```
var currentMenuItem = jQuery(".submenu li a[href='" + currentUrl + "']").parent();
```

also check if the currentUrl is equal to the href. you can output currentUrl to console for debugging like this:

```
console.log(currentUrl);
```

Comment: The sub-menu is there only to target a specific menu ... Is that wrong  to do in jQuery ? I thought it might be more correct as teh script would not need to scan all the otehr `<li>` elements - but I am speaking from a PHP mind - might be all wrong in JS ..

Comment: it is ok. but you need to either target it by its id `#sub-menu` or class `.sub-menu`. you did not show the submenu in your example code.

Comment: No.. in fact I did not . You are right . Sorry .. Will correct the question

Comment: edited the post. hope it solves your issue and explains css selectors a little